# Role of Anchors and real peer-to-peer

Tags: anchor, peers

could You let me know if direct transfers of USD credits from an account of a natural Person to another natural Person in the euro area are possible or do I need an anchor and the transaction needs to go through the pool account? Can I pay with the credits issued on the network merchants in my country or is a withdrawl necessary? If no why is it needed to convert them and what hinders the direct peer-to-peer interaction?

Best,

Jenny

Answer (score 1):

You need anchor to convert the credits to FIAT currency.